# Bar only Booktitles from beeing cited

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

The Problem i'm facing is, that I must not cite booktitles in the text. However I have to cite shorttitles for articles and the like.
My question how is: How can I only switch off the booktitles of beeing cited?

Answer (score 1):

Apparentely this can be done by using \citetitlefortype{} and including all types which need to be cited with thitle, the rest will then be ignored